# Why are absolute imports not working in my react-native expo project?

Tags: react-native, expo, absolute-path

An example of the imports follows:

```
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '~/redux/hooks'
import * as walletActions from '~/redux/wallet/actions'
import { actions, selectState as selectWalletState } from '~/redux/wallet/slice'
import { multichain } from '~/services/multichain'
import { config } from '~/settings/config'
```

In my tsconfig.json...

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*":["./src/*"]
    },
...
```

This all compiles, and typescript understands my imports; I can click around them in VSCode.
However, when I open the app in Expo, I get the error

```
Unable to resolve module ~/redux/hooks from ... ~/redux/hooks could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
```

Here is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
      [
        'module:react-native-dotenv',
        {
          envName: 'APP_ENV',
          moduleName: '@env',
          path: '.env',
        },
      ],
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: {
            '~/': './src/',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
}
```